# NtQuerySystemInformation/WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to hook NtQuerySystemInformation for hiding simple process (nothing malicious) Just trying to figure out how hooking system works.

This code compile as DLL, and using MinHook should be able to hide  "calc.exe" from process list in Task Manager. It doesn't do that, and I really can't figure out why.

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Winternl.h"
#include "MinHook.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")
#define NT_SUCCESS(Status) (((NTSTATUS)(Status)) >= 0)
typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO
{
    ULONG                   NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG                   NumberOfThreads;
    LARGE_INTEGER           Reserved[3];
    LARGE_INTEGER           CreateTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           KernelTime;
    UNICODE_STRING          ImageName;
    ULONG                   BasePriority;
    HANDLE                  ProcessId;
    HANDLE                  InheritedFromProcessId;
}SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO, *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO;

typedef NTSTATUS LONG;

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI * PNtQuerySystemInformation)(
    SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS,
    PVOID,
    ULONG,
    PULONG);

PNtQuerySystemInformation pOriginalNtQuerySystemInformation = (PNtQuerySystemInformation)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");


NTSTATUS NTAPI Detour_NtQuerySystemInformation(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass, PVOID SystemInformation, ULONG SystemInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO pCurrent, pNext;
    char *pname = NULL;

    status = pOriginalNtQuerySystemInformation(SystemInformationClass, SystemInformation, SystemInformationLength, ReturnLength);
        if (SystemInformationClass == SystemProcessInformation && NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {


            pCurrent = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO)SystemInformation;
            PWSTR g_targetProc = L"calc.exe";
            pNext = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO)((LPBYTE)pCurrent + pCurrent->NextEntryOffset);
            while (pNext->NextEntryOffset != 0)
            {
                pname = (char *)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_ZEROINIT,
                    pCurrent->ImageName.Length + 2);
                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0,
                    pCurrent->ImageName.Buffer,
                    pCurrent->ImageName.Length + 1,
                    pname, pCurrent->ImageName.Length + 1,
                    NULL, NULL);


                if (!_strnicmp((char *)pname, "calc.exe", strlen("calc.exe")))
                {
                    pCurrent->NextEntryOffset += pNext->NextEntryOffset;
                }
                pCurrent = pNext;
                pNext = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO)((LPBYTE)pCurrent + pCurrent->NextEntryOffset);
                GlobalFree(pname);
            }
    }

    return status;
}


void SetHook()
{
    MH_Initialize();
    MH_CreateHookApi(L"ntdll.dll", "NtQuerySystemInformation", &Detour_NtQuerySystemInformation, reinterpret_cast<PVOID*>(&pOriginalNtQuerySystemInformation));
    MH_EnableHook(MH_ALL_HOOKS);
}

void Unhook()
{
    MH_DisableHook(MH_ALL_HOOKS);
    MH_Uninitialize();
}
```

Comment: That is malicious by definition

Comment: even from fast look, visible several errors - first `while (pNext->NextEntryOffset != 0)` - this is error - you not process last entry. need `do { NextEntryOffset = pNext->NextEntryOffset; } while(NextEntryOffset);`. for what you convert `UNICODE_STRING` to multibyte ?? are you don't know how compare unicode strings by `RtlEqualUnicodeString` ?

Comment: also for example `SystemExtendedProcessInformation` can be used instead `SystemProcessInformation`

Comment: Done as you said. 0 changes

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i like to write those things, never used them in malicious purposes.

Comment: you need at begin set hook in own process and then call `NtQuerySystemInformation` yourself. and look how hook work under debugger

Comment: @nnhesh just a forewarning doing this in the future will likely cause a crash on any process compiled with [Control Flow Guard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt637065(v=vs.85).aspx); given that an increasing number of processes are being compiled with it this technique which is already considered malicious by microsoft and is wholly unsupported will cease too work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found out what was wrong.

i've used LoadLibraryA method for injecting dll, that looked like so:

`switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        SetHook();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        Unhook();
        break;
    }`

Unhook function were called straight after hook was placed, and then hook stopped working.
Removing Unhook function solved the problem.

Comment: You are not explaining how did you fix it?